# Backbone.js on(document).on('click') to deselect an element. Event bubbling up

Tags: jquery, events, backbone.js, event-bubbling

I am making a Backbone.js powered app, was trying different approach to detect clicks on element vs `document` and this is what I came up with:

```
initialize: function() {
  $(document).on('click', this.deselect.bind(this));
},

deselect: function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == "HTML") {
    return this.collection.deselect();
  }
}
```

It works since `<html>` element is getting passed as the event target when clicking on `document`. However [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) suggests that I should either compare `this` with `event.target` (that didn't work in my case) or stop propagation for the event.

What is the best way to do it? Also I am wondering why nobody does it like I did?

**Update:**
Since the original post I found that it is better to check if the event target is `<html>` and updated the code.

Comment: _Since there are no classes on document it works_. No, `event.target` doesn't refer to the `document` object, it refers to the element that has triggered the _click_ event.

Comment: Yep, in fact `event.target` returns `<html>` element when clicking on `document`.